# how to open a url with url_launcher and onTap of InkWell only once?

Tags: flutter

- if i touch it once then it prints out 1 line 123
- if i touch it many times then it prints out many line 123
- So how when I touch it many times then it prints out 1 line 123 or exiting _launchUrl
- When I touch it many times then I also had to go back to that number of times to get rid of _launchUrl

My code here
Hope to get everyone's help!

```
final Uri _url = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');

....


Future<void> _launchUrl() async {
    if (!await launchUrl(_url)) {
        throw 'Could not launch $_url';
    }
}

...

InkWell(
    onTap: () {
        _launchUrl;
        print('123');
    }    
)
```

I tried using the wait function but still not getting the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by following way

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev');
Navigator.of(context).push(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => LoadURL(uri),
  )
);

// Navigate to here

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class LoadURL extends StatelessWidget {
  late final Uri uri;
  LoadURL(this.uri);

  Future<void> _launchUrl(Uri uri) async {
    if (!await launchUrl(uri)) {
      throw 'Could not launch $uri';
    }
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _launchUrl(uri),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable buttonPressed and set it default to false

```
bool buttonPressed = false;
```

Inside your onTap you can check if the buttonPressed is set to false. If it is set to false you can set it to true and run your _launchUrl function. After you called _launchUrl you can set it back to false to run it again.

```
if(buttonPressed == false){
  buttonPressed = true;
  await _launchUrl();
  buttonPressed = false;
}
```

Also mark your onTap as async to use the await keyword

```
onTap: () async {
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still fails